# Getting Error in CreateTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: c#

This is the query in which i m getting error

```
CreateTableCommand.CommandText = "BACKUP DATABASE Test" +
                             "TO  DISK = 'C:\backup\t1.bak'" + 
                                 "WITH " +
                             "NOFORMAT, " +
                             "COMPRESSION," +
                             "NOINIT,  " +
                             "NAME = N't1-Full Database Backup'," + 
                             "SKIP, " +
                                 "STATS = 10;";
```

and the error is "Incorrect syntax near 'DISK'."
but if i run run that query ms sql server 2008 its work fine but when i try to use that in my C# application it gave error pls help me out

Comment: I reformatted your code. Try using the formatting features. Errors such as yours are getting pretty obvious. Moreover, it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another space after `Test`, your SQL is built to `... TestTO DISK ...`.

```
string line2 = "BACKUP DATABASE Test ";
```

As Onots pointed out, you should also escape some characters properly (`\` introduces an escape sequence, `\` itself is escaped as `\\`):

```
string line2 = "TO  DISK = \'C:\\backup\\t1.bak\'";
```

See also [MSDN: string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for details.

Comment: Also the \ in the string will be treated as an escape charachter. \b and \t are probably not what he wanted.

Comment: Cheers mate really work and i also forget to use \\ thanks but now there is another problem when i run this query from sql server management studio it create a file with size of 1,186 kb and when i use that code on c# it create a file with size of 11,853kb can you tell me why pleasee

Comment: Uhm sorry, I have no idea. You should maybe ask as a new question, since it might rather be a SQL problem and it'll be easier to find and answer then :)

Comment: sorry it was my mistake i call that function in loop which iterate till 0 to 10 my logic mistake thanks man

Answer (score 1):

For SQL statements, it's easier to use a [Verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for the whole query rather than concatenating fragments.  E.g.

```
CreateTableCommand.CommandText = @"
BACKUP DATABASE Test
TO  DISK = 'C:\backup\t1.bak'
WITH 
NOFORMAT, 
COMPRESSION,
NOINIT,
NAME = N't1-Full Database Backup',
SKIP, 
STATS = 10;
";
```